# rails has many of itself

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails

There are a few questions similar to mine, but not quite what I'm looking for

[rails many to many self join](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3396831/rails-many-to-many-self-join)

[Many-to-many relationship with the same model in rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2168442/many-to-many-relationship-with-the-same-model-in-rails)

My situation is something like User with many Friends.

```
class User
  has_many connections
  has_many friends, through: connections, class_name: 'User'
end

class Connection
  belongs to :user
  belongs to :friend, class_name: 'User'
end
```

This gets me pretty close, I can do:

```
first = User.create
second = User.create

first.friends << second
first.friends # => [ second ]
```

I would like the connection to go both ways

```
first.friends << second
second.friends # => [ first ]
```

The problem is that the "friends" query is looking in connections for the user_id of the User, and then finding all of the friend_ids.  Since there is no connection with a user_id of "second", "second" has no connections.

I am thinking two solutions.  1) Create another connection with user_id = "second" when the first connection is created. 2) override the "friends" method to produce a SQL query that will figure it out.

Any thoughts about this?  Thanks.

Comment: Sorry I don't have time for a full answer but you may find this to be helpful for your situation. http://railscasts.com/episodes/163-self-referential-association

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this

```
first.friends << second
second.friends << first
```

by this you will have both or you can make a second relation [rayn style](http://railscasts.com/episodes/163-self-referential-association)